# The best way to display availability in catalog for product that has multiple versions with different availabilities?

Tags: product, customer

What is the best way to display availability in a catalog for a product that has multiple versions (e.g., sizes) with different availabilities?

I could think of two best ways to deal with this situation:

A.) Show "in stock" if at least one product version/size is in stock.

B.) Show something like "some versions in stock" so customers won't be disappointed when a version is not available.

I thought of displaying available e.g. sizes directly in the product catalog, but it is not always just sizes, it could be also longer definitions of product versions - therefore showing this long information directly in the catalog is not an option.

Will be happy for any ideas or research references.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's an online store or if you're using an eCommerce platform, but what you explain in the question is called **variants** or **variations**. This greatly simplifies the seller's work and makes the purchase easier for the user.

If the product has color, size, description variants, or even if it's sold together with another product, each of the possible combinations has an associated **SKU number**. This number facilitates the whole process and depending on the type of product for sale, it's important that it's visible. From here there are several possibilities:

- Each SKU number is associated with a quantity in stock, so there may
  be an alert in advance in the product window specifying the SKUs
  `xxx, yyy, zzz, are temporarily out of stock`.
- As each combination of variants has an associated SKU number, when the "out of stock" SKU appears, the purchase button can change its status to deactivated with the `out of stock` message.
- Many specialty stores have a *Quick Purchase* service to buy
  by SKU number instead of by item, either manually or by uploading an
  Excel. In this case, it's very simple, in manual mode when placing
  the quantity, the form field may appear inactive with the `Out of Stock` message. If it's based on loading an Excel, a results report
  may indicate which reference is out of stock.

These come to mind immediately, but there are many more possibilities. The important thing: the SKU number associated with each variant to define stock, facilitate selection, and even helps to identify an item immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference from Lazada on how they display a similar user flow on their website. In their case, I think it works pretty good.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thank You. Maybe I did not ask the question well, but I meant how to show availability in a product list. In product detail, it is quite logical, but in the product list (in category), how would you display this availability to customers for a product that has variants with different availabilities?